# Convert DF column values to column (like pivot)

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I am scraping api data and totaling counts of different values into a dictionary 'building':'count' for each player (row). I would like to be able to analyze it further. An easy solution would be to pull the different unique 'buildings' (dictionary keys within the row) as dataframe columns and then do the equivalent of an index/match/match on them. The script currently gets the data, and I can extract the unique keys, but I am lost at how to make them into DF columns and then how to do the index/match/match. There may be a better approach from even before running the 'count' part of the script.

You should be able to run the script, no credentials are required to GET against the API. If you see the ranklist DF column with the building counts you will see what I am referencing.

Thank you for any guidance!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import operator
from time import sleep

ranklist = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(430):
    baserank_url = 'https://www.simcompanies.com/api/v3/encyclopedia/ranking/' + str(i) + '/'
    r = requests.get(baserank_url)
    rank_json = r.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rank_json)
    df=df.filter(['company','id','rank','value'])
    ranklist = ranklist.append(df)

ranklist.to_csv(r'rank_dataframe.csv',index=False)
print('Ranking list started succesfully!')

levellist=[]
bcolist=[]
today= date.today()
for row in ranklist.itertuples():
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        if attempt == 6:
            break
        try:
            print(str(row.rank + 1) +'  ' + str(attempt))
            account_url = 'https://www.simcompanies.com/api/v2/players/' + str(row.id) + '/'
            r = requests.get(account_url)
            account_json = r.json()
            playerid = account_json.get("player").get("id")
            playerlevel = account_json.get("player").get("level")
            datestart = datetime.strptime(account_json.get("player").get("dateJoined")[:10],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
            yearsactive = round((today - datestart)/ timedelta(days=365.2425),2)
            buildings = account_json.get("buildings")
            certificates = account_json.get("certificates")
            bnames = [d['name'] for d in buildings]
            bnames = [n.replace('Park','Recreation').replace('Lake','Recreation').replace('Castle','Recreation') for n in bnames]
            cnames = [d['name'] for d in certificates]
            sptr = 'Yes' if 'Supporter' in cnames else 'No'
            dictOfElems = dict()
            for elem in bnames:
                if elem in dictOfElems:
                    dictOfElems[elem] += 1
                else:
                    dictOfElems[elem] = 1
            blist = {key:value for key, value in dictOfElems.items()}
            blist = dict(sorted(blist.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
            bcolist.append([blist.keys()])
            levellist.append([playerid, playerlevel,sptr, datestart,yearsactive,blist])
    
        except:
            sleep(20)
            attempt +=1
            continue
        break

#get unique building values
bcodf= pd.DataFrame(bcolist,columns=['buildings'])
bcouni = list(set([a for b in bcodf.buildings.tolist() for a in b]))
print(bcouni)
leveldf = pd.DataFrame(levellist,columns=['id','level','sptr','datestart','yearsactive','blist'])
#clist = list(set([a for b in leveldf.cnames.tolist() for a in b]))

#print(leveldf[blist])
#bul = leveldf[blist].keys()
#buniq = list(set([a for b in leveldf.bul.tolist() for a in b]))
#print(bul)
ranklist = ranklist.merge(leveldf, on='id', how='left')
ranklist['rank'] +=1

ranklist.to_csv(r'rank_dataframe.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: This will not run, `attempt` is not defined

Comment: @Chris What line is messing up for you? It runs fine for me